# Can you work remote in Italy for a UK based company with just a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, italy, tourist-visas, working-visas

I'm a UK resident and want to vacation in Italy for **2 months in 2022**. I work as a software developer so i can work with just my laptop and internet connection. I want to work some days when i am out there and use other days for exploring/sightseeing.

My company is based in the UK. I know i've seen some other answers that have said it's technically illegal but is this enforceable and is it worth the risk? Will i be asked to show proof of time off from my employer by border control when i arrive?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128887/discussion-on-question-by-luke97-can-you-work-remote-in-italy-for-a-uk-based-com). Please go to that chatroom if you want to post (more) comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*De jure* there are dozens of complex laws and regulations regarding remote employment, under which you may or may not need a special visa in order to work remotely in a given country. Tax laws are an additional complication, where countries such as the UK can deem you as a tax resident for [spending as little as 16 days](https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/residence) on British soil. And things might be even more complicated if your employer has an office in the country of your travel.

*De facto*, as long as you don't mention your remote job to immigration personnel at the airport or your employer, there's a 99.99% chance no one will ever find out. There are [hundreds of thousands](https://www.thenewhumanitarian.org/news/2020/05/14/Italy-undocumented-migrants-work-permits) of people breaking the law by being employed at *on-site* jobs in Italy, so digital nomads are a pretty low priority for law enforcement. You're not taking away jobs from local employees so while the *letter* of the law may or may not apply to your situation strictly speaking, you won't be breaking the *spirit* of the law.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of countries these days are creating digital nomad visa's to account for traveling remote workers. Italy doesn't appear to be one of these countries though.

To work in Italy, in any capacity you do have to have a work visa. That is just in consideration with the legalities of Italy though. Your own company may have its own set of rules regarding where one can work remotely as well.

However, depending on the exact nature of your employment relationship in the UK you may be able to qualify for a self-employment visa in Italy to allow you to continue to work there while in the country.

Answer (score -6):

You need to ask your company about that & it depends on the company if your company allows then you can work remotely from anywhere in the world if your company allows.

Comment: While this answer might be true from an employer’s point of view, it is incorrect from an Immigration rules standpoint.

Comment: @Traveller is right. We were arguing above **just how many** laws the OP would be breaking.